# Click en elemento especifico de CardView

Tags: c#, recyclerview, xamarin.android, cardview

Tengo cargandose en un `RecyclerView` un `CardView` que posee 3 TextViews y 5 ImageViews; yo necesito que en este CardView hayan 2 tipos de metodos `OnClick()`.

> El primero tiene que suceder cuando se le de click a una imagen dentro
> del CardView, funcionando de forma similar a un "Like".

> El segundo tiene que suceder cuando no sea el metodo 1 (cuando se
> cliquee cualquier cosa que no sea el boton de "Like").

Yo estoy teniendo problema unicamente con el metodo 1 para identificar el `boton de "Like"`, actualmente yo lo intento identificar leyendo el `ID` del `view` que me devuelve el método OnClick:

```
public void OnClick(View view, int position, bool isLongClick)
```

El problema es que cada vez que se crean publicaciones nuevas (nuevos CardViews) ese ID cambia también, por lo que si corrijo el numero int del ID queda funcionando, pero al agregarse mas publicaciones deja de funcionar nuevamente y ya no entra en el `if` correcto del `OnClick`.

```
public void OnClick(View view, int position, bool isLongClick)
        {                          
                string identifier = (view.Id).ToString();
                IDItemChanged = position;

                if (!isLongClick) // Click corto
                {
                    if ("2131296343" == identifier) //Botón de Like // No entra en el if dado que el id ahora es diferente.
                    {
                        BtnLikeCorto(VarGlobal.NFIdsDocs[position]); // Metodo/Operacion a realizar utilizando el `position` del CardView seleccionado.    
                    }
```

Se les ocurre una forma de ubicar el botón que no varié nunca o algún workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta utilizando una propiedad disponible en casi todos los componentes llamada `Tag`.

Define el Tag en el diseño XML del Layout del `CardView` como si tal se tratara de cualquier otra propiedad como Height o Width, y en el método `OnClick()` me quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
string identifier = (view.Tag).ToString();
            IDItemChanged = position;

            if (!isLongClick) //Click corto
            {
                if ("Like" == identifier) //Boton de Me gusta - Accion simple (Not long press).
                {
                    if (VarGlobal.gFlagNFAlterno == "1")
                    {
                        LikeCorto(VarGlobal.NFIdsDocs2[position]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LikeCorto(VarGlobal.NFIdsDocs[position]);
                    }

                }
```

Quien hubiera pensado que el campo ID no era lo mas recomendado.